# Adding pages dynamically using Turn.js

Tags: turnjs

I have about 100 pages, each with an image or a video. While constructing the book I'm calling addPage on all of the 100 pages in a 'for' loop. Since Turn.js keeps only 6 pages in DOM, I assumed it was okay to load it this way. However I've seen examples of loading a few pages in range in an event handler such as when turning. What is the right approach?

Comment: https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/wiki/Making-pages-dynamically-with-Ajax look at this link